# CSS :not selector is not applying correctly

Tags: html, css, dom, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply styles to all elements except .reset-this and elements that are descendants of .reset-this. My CSS is not working. It's not applying to any elements.

```
*:not(.reset-this, .reset-this *) { //styles in here }
```

To see a live example of how it's not working, go to this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sh39L882/1/

Comment: `:not()` only allows one [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn) as its argument to my knowledge, which is why your attempt is not working.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't declare different styles to `.reset-this` (and by proxy any child elements)?

Comment: Yes - because .reset-this should be a no-style zone where all descendant elements are pure and untouched as they come default within the browser. It's just a specific requirement for my project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In CSS 3, more specifically [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument.

The key here being `simple selector`. `:not` only access simple selectors like `.classsName`, not things with a `,`, or `.className .child`.

Note however that this has been updated in [Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#negation):

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(), is a functional pseudo-class taking a selector list as an argument.

Note the change of `simple selector` to `selector list`. That means that what you are trying to do will be possible, but only in browsers implementing the new spec.

You can always apply the styles broadly and then revert them:

```
* {
  color: red
}

.reset-this, .reset-this * {
  color: black;
}
```

But that is pretty terrible and gross and ugly. As you commented, it would be much better to design your class structures to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks. I've found a solution to my specific problem, which is to just add the class "X" to every descendant of the parent class, so then I can use ":not(.X)", which satisfies the "simple selector" requirement.

Comment: Especially for inherited properties such as `color`, you *never* want to apply a hard value to `*`. If you want these properties to apply to all elements, set them on `body` and let all descendants inherit as normal. Don't try to fight the inheritance chain.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you'll have to be more specific with your styles.

Firstly, the wildcard (*) selector cannot be used with pseudo classes because it is too broad - it essentially negates the `:not` here. Instead, you can use `body :not`.

Also, pseudo classes cannot be inherited. The best alternative is to have your descendants inherit its parent's style(s).

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r4upf/sh39L882/2/

Comment: Actually `:not()` is not a pseudo element (it's a pseudo class), and `*` can be used with a pseudo element -- FYI.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - confused the two. Still, `*` can't be used with pseudo classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
*:not(.reset-this), .reset-this * {
    color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ymrsx8cx/

Comment: All 4 lines of text are red, when the goal is to make only the first and last lines red. I'm trying to exclude .reset-this and all its descendants.